# File Stream exception having trouble getting the try and catch blocks in scope

Tags: c#, filestream

I would like to handle the FileNotFoundException within this class if an incorrect file name is keyed in but cannot seem to keep everything in scope using try catch blocks. Any pointer please

The exception is thrown here (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))

```
public class XcelReader
{
    private readonly List<List<IRule>> m_Rules;

    public XcelReader(List<List<IRule>> rules)
    {
        m_Rules = rules;
    }

    public void ValidateWorksheet(string fileName)
    {
        bool allRulesPassed = true;

        WorkbookProvider workbookProvider = new WorkbookProvider();

        int counter = 0;
        IWorkbook workbook;

        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
            workbook = workbookProvider.GetWorkbook(fileStream, SpreadsheetType.Xlsx);

        for (int rowCounter = 1; rowCounter < workbook.Worksheets[1].Rows.Count; rowCounter++)
        {
            IRow row = workbook.Worksheets[1].Rows[rowCounter];

            for (int columnCounter = +1; columnCounter < row.Cells.Count; columnCounter++)
            {
                List<string> failedRules = ColumnValueIsValid(row.Cells[columnCounter].Value, m_Rules[columnCounter]);

                failedRules.ForEach(failedRule =>
                {

                    allRulesPassed = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n[{0}:{1}] Failed: {2}", rowCounter +1, GetColumnHeaderValue(columnCounter + 1), failedRule);
                    counter++;

                    if (counter > 20)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to page down................");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        counter = 0;
                    }

                });
            }
        }

        if(allRulesPassed)
            Console.WriteLine(@"WOOHOO! worksheet is hunky dory Hit enter to continue");
    }

    private string GetColumnHeaderValue(int columnCounter)
    {

       return new Base26Converter().FromBase10(columnCounter);
    }

    private List<string> ColumnValueIsValid(string value, List<IRule> rules)
    {
        List<string> failedRules = new List<string>();

         rules.ForEach(rule =>
         {
             if(!rule.IsValid(value))
                 failedRules.Add(rule.GetReasonForFailure(value));
         });

        return failedRules;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"cannot keep everything in scope"*? there is no try-catch in your code.

Comment: Just wrap using with try/catch but...why don't you **also** check with File.Exists()?!

Comment: "using" statement transforms in try {} finally {}. If you have any unhandled exception inside you will never know about it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up re the using statement I will re think the code.